# term for people who show contempt for other professions besides their own

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a term to describe or even coin for people who show little respect or who show even contempt for other professions besides their own.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Please provide any research (and possibly what words you have rejected and why).

Comment: ... hypocritcal ?

Comment: [*Andrew Mellon was an ignorant, narrow-minded **occupational chauvinist** and a domestic autocrat.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Tps_246op3EC&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=%22occupational+chauvinist%22&source=bl&ots=zn36rcvEO6&sig=ACfU3U3ah8PJa8hPW8AZ5Pr9THULL4m3lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8qoLW_6fkAhXHQkEAHTjkD98Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22occupational%20chauvinist%22&f=false) Specifically, he looked down on lawyers, doctors, teachers, etc., and expected his son to follow him as a ***farmer*** (an "occupation", even if it's not really a "profession").

Comment: The term you want is jerk ...

Comment: Why prevent others from answering? See: "... the culture of many professions is self-protective and reinforced by the camaraderie or a kind of **professional parochialism**," Melissa Morey, *Professional contempt and the minimised Executive*, seanspence.com.au/professional-contempt-minimised-executive/

Comment: Kevin Corcoran, "The Evidence-Based Internship," OUP, 2008, **p.61**.

Comment: David Kennedy, *The Twentieth Century ...* in Austin Sarat (Ed.), "Looking Back at Law's Century," 2018, Cornell U Press, **p.388**.

Comment: Mambert, *Needed—A Good Basic Communication Course*. J Tech Wrtg & Comm., 1971.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**intolerant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intolerant):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 b** : unwilling to grant or share social, political, or professional rights : BIGOTED

Note the particular inclusion of *professional* rights in the definition.

In other words, you could have a sentence like this:

> The doctor was *intolerant* of the veterinarian's opinion of how the person's wounds should be treated.

In that example, the doctor thinks that a veterinarian, being trained to treat animals, can surely not have the same level of expertise or good sense as a doctor—and dismisses their opinion out of hand for no reason other than that fact.